# Python Flask App is not starting for some Application using httpPlatform Handler in IIS version 10

Tags: python-3.x, flask, iis-10, httpplatformhandler

I have multiple applications with similar python flask app script to host in IIS\Default Web Site. Only firstly create Application is working as expected and unfortunately, other subsequent flask app are not running.

When recycle the respective appPool, I have got following error only in event viewer.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        HttpPlatformHandler
Date:          10/27/2023 3:46:44 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      
Description:
The description for Event ID 1000 from source HttpPlatformHandler cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Process '10260' failed to start. Port = 20173, Error Code = '-2147023436'.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-10-27T10:16:44.326060800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1926695</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>BAVNAPPCNV01.PEARL.COM</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Process '10260' failed to start. Port = 20173, Error Code = '-2147023436'.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpPlatform processPath="D:\Program Files (x86)\Utilities\report\report\env\Scripts\python.exe" arguments="-m flask run --port 4001">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="FLASK_APP" value="report.py" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
        <handlers>
            <add name="reportHttpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\Utilities\report\report\env\Scripts\python.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-install httpPlatformHandler and even restart the server.

Comment: Not sure which tutorial you followed, but you cannot set a fixed port https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: We can set for different fixed port for each application. These all configurations are working in multiple servers. I'm just wondering why one of the my server is not working.

Comment: I am not sure what are the "servers" you claimed in "These all configurations are working in multiple servers", but on IIS the port number should be fully controlled by HttpPlatformHandler and that's why your fixed port setting won't work.

Comment: I meant windows servers here. These fixed ports are working on some windows servers. Thanks for your suggestions, I'll try set to %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% in arguments.

Comment: use  this config file "<handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" scriptProcessor="C:\Python311\python.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python311\python.exe" arguments="-m flask run --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" startupTimeLimit="20" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\python.log">
        </httpPlatform>" and make sure you are assigning iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site root folder and python folder

Comment: Hi! LexLi, Jalpa,  All ports are working now in (4000,4001,4002..) after changing the Site App name is made same as prefix in @app.route('app1/hello') where 'app1' is also site name. I'm not sure what's the reason for this changed but worked. If you're aware, please update here. I'm looking for resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the http handler, use below web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python311\python.exe" arguments="-m flask run --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" startupTimeLimit="20" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\test.log">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

assign iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the site root folder and python folder where the python exe file located.

Comment: Some flask application are running and some are not even I changed to %HTTP_PLAFORM_PORT%. In my scenario, I've four flask applications that are trying to run on port (4000, 4001, 4002, 4003). Two apps are running on different ports which are working as expected. Other two throw errors (attached in description). It seems access permissions, I've provided full control. I have no clue since I got only error message in event viewer.

Comment: @chongthampankaj could you try setting the admin user custom account identity to the application pool